# Linq for self join

Tags: c#, linq

I am having a function

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int type { get; set; }
}

List<Employee> GetData()
{
    var emp1 = new Employee() { Id = 1, Name = "A1", type = 1};
    var emp3 = new Employee() { Id = 1, Name = "A3", type = 2};
    var emp2 = new Employee() { Id = 1, Name = "A2", type = 3};
    var emp4 = new Employee() { Id = 2, Name = "A4", type = 1};
    var emp5 = new Employee() { Id = 2, Name = "A5", type = 2};
    var emp6 = new Employee() { Id = 2, Name = "A6", type = 3};

    var empList = new List<Employee>() { emp1, emp2, emp3, emp4, emp5, emp6 };
    return empList;
}
```

Then I have a function which will be called to filter a data

```
public class KeyVal
{
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public void filterData(KeyVal keyVal1, KeyVal keyVal2)
{
    //keyVal1 = {Type = 1, Vlaue = "A1"}
    //keyVal1 = {Type = 2, Vlaue = "A2"}

    var empList = GetData();
    //Some linq
}
```

I want the result in such way that,
I want to group a data on Id basis

```
Id     Value
 1   Name: "A1", Type: 1
     Name: "A3", Type: 2
     Name: "A2", Type: 3
 2   Name: "A4", Type: 1
     Name: "A5", Type: 2
     Name: "A6", Type: 3
```

And based on input `'KeyVal keyVal1, KeyVal keyVal2'`
If key and value in same group matches return that object.
i.e

```
keyVal1 = {1 , "A1"}
keyVal2 = {3 , "A2"}
```

it should return group 1

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to achieve

Comment: have understand the data structure

Comment: Yes, the data structure makes your idea nonsense

Comment: i just simply doing grouping of emp based on id, and its sample app. Don't you understand the op want?

Comment: I don't see where are you using linq to do it

Comment: I know the solution but i would like to see your tries ^^

Comment: Ohh man that't the problem. I don't know how to do it

Comment: Okay let's mark my answer

Comment: I just change the code plz check getFilterData function

Comment: Please show what you have tried. There are many questions for grouping by a key

Comment: they can't have the same id, it's logically wrong.

Comment: Question is very simple, i am making group. Group contains few element, if all matches. then select that group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to group your results by the `Id` and then project the `KeyVal`:

```
var result = empList.GroupBy(key => key.Id, val => new KeyVal(val.type, val.name));
```

Or using query syntax:

```
var result = from item in empList
             group new KeyVal(item.type, item.Name) by item.Id into g
             select new { Id = g.Key, Value = g.ToList() };
```

---

Given a use input of type `KeyVal` to find the matching group:

```
var group = result.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Any(item => item.Type == input.Type &&
                                                     item.Value == input.Value));
```

If you override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` then you can:

```
var group = result.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Contains(input));
```

---

For two objects as user input:

```
var group = result.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Contains(input1) && g.Contains(input2));
```

For big amounts of data you can project the nested collection as a `HashSet<KeyVal>` and then the `Contains` will be in `O(1)` and not `O(n)` taking it down from a total of `O(n^2)` to `O(n)` (without counting the time of the grouping operation.

Comment: that i know but how do i apply where clause. That's my main problem. User will give me two input. Where should i put that in where clause

Comment: @HemantMalpote - then question is very unclear. It does not explain about any where clause...

Comment: I want a group which matches the given input

Comment: It works for first input only, how about both input match